# What is the difference between 'else' and 'else if' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am confused between 'else' and 'else if' or 'elif' in python. I do understand that an else does not need a condition whereas an else if does need a condition as it still an if clause. Is there any other difference between these two clauses and in the way we use them? Any sort of help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See [Conditional Statements in Python: else/elif](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/#the-else-and-elif-clauses).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation

Answer (score 2):

In languages like C, there was no `elif` keyword; there were only nested `if-else` statements. (I only use C as an example of not having `elif`, rather than claiming that no previous or contemporary languages did not.)

```
/* Pretend print is a defined function */
if (x == 1) {
    print("one");
} else {
    /* x != 1 */
    if (x == 2) {
        print("two");
    } else {
        print("many");
    }
}
```

Because each body only needs to be a statement, not necessarily a compound statement, the bracket in the above can be dropped.

```
if (x == 1)
    print("one");
else
    if (x == 2)
        print("two");
    else
        print("many");
```

and because indentation and newlines are just arbitrary whitespace, you can rewrite this to look *almost* like a single statement.

```
/* Still two statements */
if (x == 1)
    print("one");
else if (x == 2)
    print("two");
else
    print("many");
```

Other languages took the step of "merging" `else` and `if` into a single keyword to allow conditional statements with more than one condition. `python` and POSIX shell uses `elif`. (`perl` is an example of language with a different keyword, `elsif`.)

The nested statement

```
if x == 1:
    print("one")
else:
    if x == 2:
        print("two")
    else:
        print("many")
```

becomes

```
if x == 1:
    print("one")
elif x == 2:
    print("two")
else:
    print("many")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Elif** (else-if) - lets you check for multiple expressions.
**Else** - Basically means if not true then...
*Example*

```
num = random.randint(1,2)
if num == 1:
    print("The number is 1")
elif num == 2:
    print("The number is 2")
else:
    print("The number is neither 1 or 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

`else` captures every other condition not captured by `if` or `elif`. `elif` acts like a ladder to capture extra but totally different conditions than `if`. There is no `else if` statement in python.